# If a sequence is not cauchy, may the limit of this sequence not exist (not finite or infinite sequence)

Tags: calculus, limits

If a sequence is not cauchy, may the limit of this sequence not exist (not finite or infinite limit)?

I proved a sequence is not cauchy, does it mean it only converges to infinity?

Comment: No. For instance $a_n = (-1)^n$ is not Cauchy, but doesn't diverge to $\pm\infty$ either.

Comment: @SimonS. So a sequence is not cauchy, then it implies only it does not converge to a finite number?

Comment: Yes. Every convergent sequence is Cauchy. (And convergent means "to a finite number".)

Comment: @SimonS. What is the regular approach to show limit of a sequence does not exist?

Comment: The standard approach is to prove that every convergent sequence is Cauchy. Search and you will find it. Then deduce the contrapositive: a sequence that is not Cauchy is not convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  "Not Cauchy" and "diverges to infinity" are very different.

For instance, consider the sequence $a_n=(-1)^n$. This sequence is not Cauchy, but certainly doesn't diverge to infinity.